# ImageResizing Not Working In Hosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, image-resizing, imageresizer

I have an asp.net mvc project. I installed [imageresizing](http://imageresizing.net/docs/install/nuget) nuget packages. It's working in local.

When I published to my hosting then it's not working.
I set IIS situation integrated and classic but still didn't work. 
I couldn't solve, can you help please? Thanks.

The following definitions are exist in web.config

```
 <resizer>
    <plugins>
      <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
      <add name="DiskCache" />
      <add name="SimpleFilters" />
      <add name="PrettyGifs" />
    </plugins>
  </resizer>
```

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
    </modules>
```

Comment: Can you access the diagnostics page /resizer.debug.ashx ? If not, we need the entire Web.Config file to help you.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist, I can use like this format in localhost. But it's not working in hosting. 

**example.com/images/gallery-1-big.jpg?w=185&h=136&quality=60&mode=crop&anchor=topleft&cache=default**

Also I haven't .ashx file
[Look at web.config](http://adafirin.com/webconfig.txt)

Comment: The debug page isn't a static file, it's a dynamic page you access from your browser.

Comment: I see now ok. The resizer.debug = http://adafirin.com/resizer.debug.ashx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The self-diagnostics page at /resizer.debug explains the configuration issues present on your hosting environment

Image resizer diagnostic sheet      24.11.2014 22:15:04

2 Issues detected:

- (Critical):   Grant the website SecurityPermission to call UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal
          Without this permission, it may be possible for users to bypass UrlAuthorization rules you have defined for your website, and access images that would otherwise be protected. If you do not use UrlAuthorization rules, this should not be a concern. You may also re-implement your security rules by handling the Config.Current.Pipeline.AuthorizeImage event.
- DiskCache(ConfigurationError):    Not working: Your NTFS Security permissions are preventing the application from writing to the disk cache
          Please give user  read and write access to directory "D:\inetpub\adafirin.com\www\imagecache" to correct the problem. You can access NTFS security settings by right-clicking the aformentioned folder and choosing Properties, then Security.